# How do I reach a DevStack instance setup on HOST A, from HOST B (located on the same network)?

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron

I've setup two GCP instances, both with an adapter subnet `10.0.3.0/24` (HOST A: `10.0.3.7`, HOST B: `10.0.3.6`). Both have DevStack setup on them with the following `local.conf` :

HOST A: https://pastebin.com/m3sXPaz9

HOST B: https://pastebin.com/311qjqbh

According to the documentation, (https://docs.openstack.org/neutron-vpnaas/latest/contributor/testing-with-devstack.html):

> You can use two DevStack nodes connected by a common “public” network to test VPNaaS. The second node can be set up with the same public network as the first node, except it will use a different gateway IP (and hence router IP).

And,

> With DevStack running on East and West and connectivity confirmed (make sure you can ping one router/GW from the other), you can perform these VPNaaS CLI commands.

However, after following the above AND the following SO question previously asked([How to expose the Devstack floating ip to the external world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109557/how-to-expose-the-devstack-floating-ip-to-the-external-world)), **I can't get HOST B to ping the Floating IP assigned to a DevStack instance(10.0.3.156) in A.**

I have made sure that the Security groups both in GCP and DevStack allow all ingress and egress traffic on all ports. `br-ex` has the GW of `10.0.3.129`, which is also not reachable.
[An image of the network in HOST A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffxnB.png)

Comment: I'm also aware about the setup as shown [here](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/neutron.html). Does my issue have anything to do with how the router is configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so the thing I overlooked was that even the VMs had a firewall, and i just had to add a UWF rule to them to allow traffic from devices on that network.